# Cron Fail: Sessions

Tags: cron-job, cron

When running the cron by visiting or curling the URL:

A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in drupal_environment_initialize()

Any advice? I'm suspicious of my permission settings.

I have a specially created cron user, who has admin permission.

Drupal 7.56 v.4.7.22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not a direct answer to your question, but you should run the cron from the cli - eg. using drush on drupal -. it bypasses all the problems and limitations of a webserver, eg timeout or memory...

as for your message, i have the same configuration and i do not experience the problem. did you change something on how the session is managed on drupal?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll give it a go and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Fixed up some permission issues (indicated by drush) and then it fixed up. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: For anyone looking, my command is 00 * * * * cd /var/www/drupal && /usr/local/bin/drush --quiet civicrm-api -u 1 job.execute